# Find out available mobile network bands in my area and disable scanning for unused bands

Tags: battery-life, cellular-radio, baseband

I have an HTC 626g+ which was supposed to be released in India, but I'm using it in Russia, which probably has different cellular frequencies available. I've read on certain forums that smartphones try to scan and find the best band available, and sometimes they are set to scan for bands that are not supposed to work at all, which allegedly wastes precious battery life.

I would like to know if disabling scanning for unused bands would save any significant amount of battery life (10 minutes is significant IMO) and if so, how to figure out which bands can be used.

Comment: I don't think mobile devices scan *all* available frequencies- they only scan the frequencies used by the service provider

Comment: [This guide at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/general/how-to-add-rf-lte-frequency-bands-to-t2886059) reinforces my point above-that being the case, i am not sure how battery is wasted

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience messing with the bands on my HTC One M8 & M9, disabling CDMA and unused WCDMA bands no significant impact on battery life.

If you want to figure out which bands can be used, a quick search on "carrier" + "bands" will tell you.